# Api cloud Whatsapp no responde mensaje. PHP

Tags: php, api, whatsapp, cloud

Estoy probando la nueva API de Whatsapp cloud,

Tengo el siguiente codigo PHP en una URL como un webhooks:

```
<?php

  $my_verify_token='probando';

  $challenge=$_GET['hub_challenge'];
  $verify_token=$_GET['hub_verify_token'];

  if($my_verify_token===$verify_token){
    echo $challenge;
    exit;
  }

  $access_token='ACA_TENGO_MI_TOKEN';

  $response = file_get_contents("php://input");

  //creo un archivo .txt para corroborar que el token sea valido. con la respuesta
  file_put_contents("text.txt" ,$response);

  $response=json_decode($response,true);

  //capturamos el mensaje que se envia al numero de prueba
  $message = $response['entry'][0]['messaging_product'][0]['messages']['text'];

  //file_put_contents("text.txt" , $message);

  $rta_message = '{
  "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
  "recipient_type": "individual",
  "to": "5492923690749",
  "type": "text",
  "text": { // the text object
    "preview_url": false,
    "body": "MESSAGE_CONTENT"
  }
}';



  send_reply($access_token,$rta_message);



  function send_reply($access_token='',$rta_message=''){
    $url="https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/ACATENGOMIID/messages/?access_token=$access_token";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $headers = array('Content-Type: application/json');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $rta_message);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $st=curl_exec($ch);
    $result = json_decode($st,TRUE);
    file_put_contents("resultado.txt" , json_encode($result));
    return $result;
  }

?>
```

El archivo text.txt se genera cuando yo envio un mensaje al numero de testing que genera whatsapp, y el resultado del .txt es el siguiente:

```
    {"object":"whatsapp_business_account",
"entry":[{"id":"101652535897740",
"changes":[{"value":{"messaging_product":"whatsapp","metadata":{"display_phone_number":"15550390980","phone_number_id":"100657435999568"},
"contacts":[{"profile":{"name":"_emi"},"wa_id":"5492923690749"}],"messages":[{"from":"5492923690749","id":"wamid.HBgNNTQ5MjkyMzY5MDc0ORUCABIYIDJGRDhGNkIyQjc5MzAyQ0IxNEUyNTlFQjkwN0ZCQjBFAA==","timestamp":"1653274087","text":{"body":"Q"},"type":"text"}]},"field":"messages"}]}]}
```

El problema es que no puedo generar una respuesta automatica, cuando un usuario escribe a este numero. Y asi poder crear una chat bot en Whatsaap.

Edit: Como ven al terminar la funcion send_reply tambien creo un .txt que el resultado es el siguiente:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) The parameter messaging_product is required.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"AJglbn8ipbj2asXrMSrj-39"}}
```

Comment: @Marcos Cambie lo que me comentas, el error persiste. Me llama la atencion que el error dice **The parameter messaging_product is required** pero lo tengo declarado a ese parametro. Sinceramente no se.

Comment: No me dí cuenta que `$rta_message` ya es una cadena. Hace esto, crea un arreglo y convertilo a `JSON` usando `json_encode`. Puede que el problema sea el comentario que pusiste o algun problema con la codificación. No te olvides de verificar que `json_encode` no te devuelva `false` (es decir, que fallo.)

Comment: @Marcos el json_encode devuelve lo que publique a lo ultimo.

Answer (score 0):

Hola no se si ya resolviste esto pero yo note algunas cosas en tu codigo

estaba asi

```html
function send_reply($access_token='',$rta_message=''){
    $url="https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/ACATENGOMIID/messages/?access_token=$access_token";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $headers = array('Content-Type: application/json');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $rta_message);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $st=curl_exec($ch);
    $result = json_decode($st,TRUE);
    file_put_contents("resultado.txt" , json_encode($result));
    return $result;
  }
```

```
$url="https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/ACATENGOMIID/messages/?access_token=$access_token";
$ch = curl_init();
$headers = array('Content-Type: application/json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $rta_message);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$st=curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($st,TRUE);
file_put_contents("resultado.txt" , json_encode($result));
return $result;
```

}

reemplazalo por esto

```html
function send_reply($rta_message){
    $url="https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/ACATENGOMIID/messages";
    $ch = curl_init();
    
$headers = array(
       "Content-Type: application/json",
       "Authorization: Bearer aquivatutoken "
    );

    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $rta_message);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $st=curl_exec($ch);
    $result = json_decode($st,TRUE);
    file_put_contents("resultado.txt" , json_encode($result));
    return $result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Validando tu código es correcto lo único que cuando envíes la respuesta utiliza una plantilla porque después de 24hrs si no hay interacción siempre tienes que enviar plantillas y no mensajes solo de texto.

```
         {
            "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
            "to":"numeroCel",
            "type": "template",
            "template": {
                "name": "hello_world",
                "language": {
                    "code": "en_US"
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: el error:  {"error":{"message":"(#100) The parameter messaging_product is required.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"AJglbn8ipbj2asXrMSrj-39"}} se esta recorriendo mal el JSON tiene que ser asi:  $response['entry'][0]['changes'][0]['value']['messages'][0]['text']['body'];

Answer (score 0):

El problema que estas teniendo está aqui, debes eliminar el comentario, me paso el mismo problema y lo solucione de esta forma

"text": { // the text object
"preview_url": false,
"body": "MESSAGE_CONTENT"
}

"text": {
"preview_url": false,
"body": "MESSAGE_CONTENT"
}

Comment: No aplica. En el caso del codigo publicado en la pregunta el marcador de comentario de linea `//` no esta modificando la estructura del json como so lo hace en el caso en que a usted le sirvió.

Comment: Si, Si, Así como dices es, no debería tener ningún efecto, pero por alguna razón da error cuando intentas mandar el sms, yo copie el ejemplo directo de la documentación e hice las pruebas con postman y el sms no salia hasta que quite ese comentario, yo jamas pensé que podría ser eso, solo con quitar el comentario logre que el sms saliera, un poco raro pero cierto

Answer (score -1):

Usa el SDK de PHP para la Api de WhatsApp Cloud de Github https://github.com/netflie/whatsapp-cloud-api

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).