# Whatsapp API Cloud PHP error al enviar nueva línea

Tags: php, webhook, facebook-graph-api

Estoy utilizando el código que aparece aquí: [Api cloud Whatsapp no responde mensaje. PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/535939/api-cloud-whatsapp-no-responde-mensaje-php)
La función que intento, es para responder un mensaje recibido de un usuario vía whatsapp y responderle con distintos productos.

Ahora bien, en mi caso, la respuesta he podido enviarla en las pruebas, sin embargo no veo forma de colocar el texto separado por líneas. He intentado con \n, con /n, con %0a, con /n/r, con \n\r

En todos los casos, el api de whatsapp lo toma como un texto normal; es decir, no hace la separación de línea sino que escribe lo mismo que uno está enviando. Lo que recibe el usuario como respuesta es algo como esto:

```
Store: A1/nTEST PRODUCT    (8)/nStore: A/nTEST PRODUCT    (12)/nStore: B/nTEST PRODUCT    (27)/nStore: C/nTEST PRODUCT    (30)/nStore: D/nTEST PRODUCT    (36)/nStore: E/nTEST PRODUCT    (41)/n
```

Luego, intenté colocar el texto concatenado con el chr(10) y también chr(13), pero en esos casos obtengo el error

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) The parameter messaging_product is required.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"AnV_8cLQp7sirNgUbciFbpx"}}
```

El punto en la aplicación en que se prepara el mensaje y se envía es aquí:

```
       $rta_message = '{
            "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
            "recipient_type": "individual",
            "to": "'.$envia.'",
            "type": "text",
            "text": { 
                "preview_url": false,
                "body": "'.$texto_respuesta.'"
            }
        }';
    
        send_reply($access_token,$rta_message,$identificador_telefono);
```

La función que envía el mensaje es esta:

```
function send_reply($access_token='',$rta_message='',$identificador_telefono=''){
    $url="https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/$identificador_telefono/messages/?access_token=$access_token";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $headers = array('Content-Type: application/json');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $rta_message);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $st=curl_exec($ch);
    $result = json_decode($st,TRUE);
    file_put_contents("resultado.txt" , json_encode($result));
    return $result;
}
```

La variable $texto_respuesta contiene el texto que deseo enviar al usuario. Es formada a partir de una función que consulta a una base de datos. Esa función, devuelve los resultados ya como mensaje formateado colocando los saltos de línea donde se supone que van.

Debo hacer notar que los mensajes son enviados correctamente, a menos que coloque el chr(10) o chr(13), pero el formato con el que queda el mensaje sin los saltos, es ilegible para el usuario.

Intenté igualmente con `<br>` asumiendo que interpretaría html, pero no lo hace. Escribe el `<br>` en el mensaje y no asume el salto de línea.

¿Alguien tiene una idea de cómo enviar saltos de línea en el mensaje usando el Cloud API?

Un millón de gracias por adelantado.

Edit: Coloqué `<br>` en código porque, a diferencia del API de WhatsApp, Stack Overflow si asume que es un salto de línea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo. Solventado.
Para que quede en los registros, hay que colocar `\\n`

La razón, a pesar de ser obvia, se me escapó de la mente.

Secuencias de escape. Si se quiere colocar en un string una comilla doble, o un backslash, en algunos lenguajes hay que utilizar una secuencia de escape. Se genera colocando un backslash antes del caracter que se desea insertar.

Por ejemplo:

```
\\ insertaría un \
\" insertaría una comilla
y en el caso que se expuso, \\n inserta un \n en el string.
```

Con eso el texto sale bello, con su salto de línea.

Agradecido de todas formas con toda la comunidad por este sitio

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Comment: me pregunto si entendiste por que tienes que usar `\\n`

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Si, porque estoy haciendo escape del caracter \n. Se me prendió el bombillo al ver el texto de prueba en la página de meta, donde hacen el escape a la comilla doble. Intenté y voilà.

Comment: @padaleiana Si, lo tengo en mis pendientes. Gracias

Comment: Está bien. Por cierto, a lo que se refiere @ArcanisGK507 es que edites tu respuesta para explicar por qué utilizaste `\\n` (¡los comentarios son volátiles!)

Comment: @padaleiana Listo; editado. Agradecido.